# which Java reporting tool to use in 2010 for small/medium webapp

Tags: java, reporting, report

We have a web app with a few forms and some integration with mobile apps. We will be producing reports from the data collected in the forms and the mobile apps. which tool should we choose given how mature they are today as well as how mature they will be in a years time ?

We are a NON-PROFIT so the lesser the expense, the better. I understand that JasperReports, Pentaho and BIRT are the leading contenders but are there other solutions that we should look at ? What factors should be kept while narrowing on the solution ?

Just so you know, we would like tool to be developed on Windows and deployable on Linux. Also, the webapp has been built using GWT.

Thank you,

Answer (score 6):

Might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238527/what-is-the-best-report-engine-for-java), BTW...

But anyways, here's my honest (yet biased) answer copied from there:

**[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear)** (used to be called i-net Crystal-Clear)

- Simple and easy-to-use API of both the report engine and the [Java report viewer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/guides/Guide_Viewer_Programming.pdf).
- Can export into any major format like PDF, HTML, SVG, XLS, etc., as well as into a Java applet viewer. (See [samples](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/samples/applications/default.asp))
- Comes with a free and powerful graphical report template designer. (See [video guide](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/guides/video/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html))
- Installs as a WAR file on your application server or can be used as a library within your own application.
- Great technical support (you usually get an answer in minutes or hours rather than days or weeks)
- Charts based on [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) (so includes Stock charts).
- Can read Crystal Reports templates. (for a lot of customers, this is the killer feature since you don't have to re-create all your old Crystal Reports templates)
- Great and competitive pricing - **effectively costing "[less than open source](http://www.inetsoftware.de/support/news/why-i-net-crystal-clear-costs-less-than-open-source)"** will cost you if you calculate in support costs (which you definitely should).
- Free [90-day trial](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/download_update.asp).
- Free yet fully functional [report designer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/designer)

[full disclosure: Yes, I work for i-net software. But it's still my honest (though subjective and biased) answer to the question. ;)]

Comment: Perhaps you should have mentioned the 1690 US$ per CPU price tag.

Answer (score 1):

Beside BIRT and i-net Clear you will find a great modern 2011-ish tool called **[iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport)**, which is a perfect report designer that sits on top of Jasper Reports.

iReport is the free, open source report designer for JasperReports. Create very sophisticated layouts containing charts, images, subreports, crosstabs and much more. Access your data through JDBC, TableModels, JavaBeans, XML, Hibernate, CSV, and custom sources. Then publish your reports as PDF, RTF, XML, XLS, CSV, HTML, XHTML, text, DOCX, or OpenOffice.